# Reformat an output in Bash

Tags: bash, ffmpeg

I'm using this ffmpeg argument to get the black frame in a file:

```
ffmpeg -i ${arrayDesFichiers[$i]} -vf "blackdetect=d=3:pix_th=0.00" -an -f null - 2>&1 | grep black_duration >> log.txt
```

Now I'm getting this in my log.txt:

```
[blackdetect @ 0x7fd9add06bc0] black_start:0 black_end:3.2 black_duration:3.2
```

And I would like to reformat it to something like this:

```
black duration : 3.2 seconds
```

I'm pretty sure it's possible in Bash but how ?

Comment: I'd suggest to use **grep** to select the string you want and **sed** to wrap the colon with blanks... Or use **awk**.

Comment: I'm trying with sed but oh boy I have such a hard time with regex… Can I say "replace everything that ends with 'black_duration' " ?

Comment: I do not understand why you have accepted the @codeforester's answer. In your question text you **ask for reformating** `black_duration:3.2`, which cannot be done by the `grep` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
ff_output=$(ffmpeg -i ${arrayDesFichiers[$i]} -vf "blackdetect=d=3:pix_th=0.00" -an -f null - 2>&1 | grep -oE "black_duration:[[:digit:]][.[:digit:]]*")
printf "%s seconds\n" "$ff_output" >> log.txt
```

---

`grep -oE "black_duration:[[:digit:]]+[.[:digit:]]*`

- `-o` option restricts the `grep` output to just the matched part
- `-E` chooses extended regex
- `[[:digit:]]+[.[:digit:]]*` looks for one or more digits, optionally followed by a period and one or more digits

Comment: I realized that limitation and modified the regex to look for an optional decimal part.